# Plotting InterpolationFunction over Quantities

Tags: plotting, interpolation, units

What's the proper syntax to plot Interpolation functions defined over Quantities?

```
points = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 0}};
```

Change domain to Quantities:

```
points2 = points // Map[Replace[{x_, y_} :> {Quantity[x, "Days"], y}]];
```

Interpolate:

```
ifun2 = Interpolation[points2];
```

This works:

ifun[Quantity[2.5, "Days"]]

> 3.6875

But where's the plot:

```
 Plot[ifun2[x], {x, Quantity[0, "Days"], Quantity[5, "Days"]}]
```

(* empty *)

Yet this works:

```
 Plot[2 x, {x, Quantity[0, "Days"], Quantity[5, "Days"]}]
```

Oddly given this non-interpolated function over Quantities:

```
f[x_] := 2*Quantity[x, "Days"]
```

This works too, ie, argument x is already a Quantity:

```
 Plot[f[x], {x, Quantity[0, "Days"], Quantity[5, "Days"]}]
```

Comment: I would use `ListPlot@Table[ifun2[x], {x, Quantity[0, "Days"], Quantity[5, "Days"]}]`

Comment: Here's a start for an answer: `ifun[QuantityMagnitude@x]`, since you're not interpolating over `Quantity` object but numbers.  Alternatively, you can interpolate over `Quantity[.., "Days"]` (change `points`), but there is either a bug or poor design choice in the way `Plot` deals/strips `Quantity` from the input. You can do `Plot[ifun3[Quantity[x, "Days"]], {x, 0, 5}]`.  Neither quite gets what I think you're after, which seems unreachable to me right now.

Comment: @MichaelE2, by your suggestion, there is no point in using Quantities, which is the motivation of the question.

Comment: Yes, that is my tentative conclusion. Or rather, I might say that it seems to me that for your use-case, `Quantity` has not been robustly implemented.  IMO, your expectation that it would work is reasonable, and you should consider reporting it to WRI.

Comment: @MichaelE2, wil do that, thanks.